# Getting Data out of Android phone suffering from Google Apps stopped working endless loop

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, crashes

One of our Moto E2 LTE is constantly displaying a "Google app has stopped error" message on power-up, rendering it useless. This occurred after the phone ran out of battery, but this could be a coincidence.

I am hoping a factory reset will resolve the issue, but before I do that, there are a few pictures on the phone we would like to retrieve. (1)

This is what I know and have attempted up to now:

- It's running Android 6.0 as provided by the carrier (no modifications)
- Debug mode is not enabled on the phone, the bootloader is Locked. (At least that is my understanding since it reports 'Device Locked' in the bootloader screen.)
- Connecting the phone to Windows shows an empty folder (since Debug is off)
- The screen is normally unlocked using a gesture, I know the gesture.
- The phone doesn't offer to answer call anymore
- Pressing "Ok" on the error message restart the application, but it fails again within second...pressing ok many times doesn't help...
- I get the same error when it starts in safe mode. The safe mode label is visible in the lower left corner of the screen.
- Looking at the bug report the phone wants to send, the error is an exception related to SQLite: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException
- Swiping the top of the screen reveals the usual menu showing the time, battery and reception power level, but it doesn't interact beyond that. The setting screen that would be available this way is not reachable.
- Going into recovery mode and wiping the cache partition didn't fix the problem (attempted twice)
- I can connect to the phone using an USB cable and see the device with Fastboot or ADB in sideload mode only.
- Since debug is not enabled I don't see the device on normal ADB

I read many posts about data recovery this week-end, but none of them would work we the situation I am facing (No Debug, cannot access settings). Or they would state that it should be possible to do something using sideload mode but don't provide any clear solution or instruction.

I have a background in telecom equipment engineering, including cell phones in the early 2000's. So I am confortable with low level manipulations, but at the same time I am not confortable injecting code in the phone from an unknown third party.

Is there a clean and relatively strait forward way of getting to the phone picture folder or should I give up?

(1) They have sentimental value and were not synchronised with a web based storage.

**Update:**
We gave up, at some point having a functional phone was more important than the lost data. The only good news is that the erase all data function in recovery mode worked and the phone is functional again.

Also, I made sure the debug mode is now active on the phone!

Comment: Did you try safe boot?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the same error when it starts in safe mode. The safe mode label is visible in the lower left corner of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried using a different account or creating a new user account and use it, another method that I can think of is mounting the phone storage and use it on pc

Comment: Mounting the phone as storage doesn't provide access to the data, I get an empty folder. But since I cannot unlock the phone, this is expected. I also cannot change the user, because the interface at the top of the screen where I could do this is unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using aroma file manager and transfer the files using it to usb otg. 
1. Is your bootloader unlocked?
2.Aroma file manager workes only in custom recovery like TWRP

Comment: My understanding is that the phone is bootloader is locked. On the fastboot page there is a line stating: Device is LOCKED. Status Code: 0 Won't unlocking the bootloader erase all data?

Comment: @LucDallaire yes that was what i was asking. It would be meaninglessness to unlock bootloader to recover data if it erases all the data. One more thing is their nothing like mtp mode when you connect your phone to pc ?

Comment: When connect in media transfert mode (camera) it report that there is nothing to import, but suggest to unlock the device and try again. With the Google App crash I don't get access to the unlock screen so it is another dead-end. (I also attempted this in safe boot mode)

Comment: @LucDallaire the camera mode is ptp . Is there no chance that you can swipe the notification bar and change ptp to mtp ?